# Gmail Add-ons Developer Preview Invitation

Tags: gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We develop Gmail Extensions and recently saw and applied to be included in the proposed Gmail Add-ons Developer Preview...

We have not had a Response from Google.

Has anybody been accepted into the Preview?

All I can find on the web is the following

https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/bring-power-of-your-apps-into-gmail_9.html

Thanks for your feedback
Paul C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still no definite date as to when the Invitations will be sent out. If you have filled out [the form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfx2cbX-XQT9_mu6n2DarJZt9XwDfa-TiDPzE5d2TOtrhRR2g/viewform?c=0&w=1), next thing to do is to simply wait for the announcement/email.

As also stated in the form:

> Please be advised that space in this program is limited. Applications will be reviewed on a one-on-one basis.

It's either still being reviewed or is already processed and just waiting for the invites. I suggest [following G Suite Developers](https://twitter.com/intent/follow?original_referer=https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com//&screen_name=GSuiteDevs) Twitter account (seen in the page) to be aware of any updates. I think if they would announce something like that if it comes live. Cheers!

Comment: @PNC With all that said, I think your answer is *off-topic* for Stack Overflow and there's a chance for it to be closed.